# Scroll text method, works with arrays, not with string

Tags: javascript

Basic javascript function to scroll the text in the title bar, I'm calling it via a `setInterval("rotateTitle()", 1000);` call after `onload`.

This function, which takes text from an array, works perfectly.

```
var counter = 0;
function rotateTitle() {
    var baseTitle = "www.mydomain.com - now with JavaScript";
    var titleArray = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
    var titleString = "abcdefg";
    var scrollText = getNextScroll(titleArray);
    window.document.title=baseTitle.concat(scrollText);
}

function getNextScroll(inValue) {
    var str = " ";
    for (var i = 0; i<inValue.length; i++) {
        var index = i+counter;
        if (i+counter >= inValue.length) {
            index -= inValue.length;
        }
        str += inValue[index];
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter > inValue.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Edited here for clarity:

Now if I rewrite the function to scroll a string (not an array), I change the line

`str += inValue[index];` 
to 
`str.concat(inValue.charAt(index));`

and change `getNextScroll(titleArray)` to `getNextScroll(titleString)`, the script seems to execute, but only the `baseTitle` is shown.

Why is this wrong?

Comment: @Teemu - the function works just fine just as is in the first code block, truncation doesn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of `str.concat` back to `str`; otherwise you'll miss the `concat` operation. Instead of `charAt` you must use `inValue[index]`.

Do like this:

```
str = str.concat(inValue[index]);
```

Here's a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/aCEBAju/2/

In your original code you have this:

```
str.concat(inValue.charAt(index));
```

debugging in Chrome it barks: ***array has no method charAt***.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm doing, but reassigning `str.concat()` to `str` solved the problem.  Inside `concat()` I still have `inValue.charAt(index))`, because I'm re-writing the function to scroll strings instead of arrays, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @nexus_2006 ok... but Google Chrome debugger barked in this line: `str.concat(inValue.charAt(index));` - even when passing `titleString` as the parameter.

Comment: thats strange, neither the debugger or the console in Firefox has anything to say at all, no errors, warnings, etc.  When you pass in `titleString`, `inValue` is a string, and so should have the `charAt()` method, right?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is that `str.concat(inValue.charAt(index));` must change to `str = str.concat(inValue.charAt(index));` or `str += inValue.charAt(index);`.  `Str` must be assigned the new value.  This is the entire working function:

```
var counter = 0;
function rotateTitle() {
    var baseTitle = "www.berrmal.com - now with JavaScript";
    var titleArray = new Array("b","e","r","r","m","a","l");    //no longer necessary
    var titleString = "berrmal: bigger, longer, uncut";
    var scrollText = getNextScroll(titleString);
    window.document.title=baseTitle.concat(scrollText);
}

function getNextScroll(inString) {
    var str = " ";
    for (var i = 0; i<inString.length; i++) {
        var index = i+counter;
        if (i+counter >= inString.length) {
            index -= inString.length;
        }
        str += inString.charAt(index);
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter > inString.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    return str;
}
```

I figured out the answer to the problem based on Leniel Macaferi's answer, though his posted code is not correct.  This method runs successfully in Firefox 23.0 with no error in the console.